# How to control mysql with zpty?

Tags: zsh, pipe, io-redirection, mysql, tty

I try to write a wrapper script for the mysql console client. While working on this, I stumbled upon zpty. It seems perfect.

My first goal was to retrieve some table contents, but I already fail doing this. There is some really strange behaviour.

If I run zsh and type in myself

```
$ zmodload zsh/zpty
$ zpty -b MYSQL mysql DATABASE-NAME
$ zpty -r MYSQL
```

everything works as expected and

```
Reading table information for completion of table and column names
You can turn off this feature to get a quicker startup with -A

Welcome to the MariaDB monitor.  Commands end with ; or \g.
Your MySQL connection id is 448
Server version: 5.5.54-0+deb8u1 (Debian)

Copyright (c) 2000, 2016, Oracle, MariaDB Corporation Ab and others.

Type 'help;' or '\h' for help. Type '\c' to clear the current input statement.

MySQL [DATABASE-NAME]> %
```

is printed.

If I put the same lines of code in a shellscript

```
#!/bin/zsh
zmodload zsh/zpty
zpty -b MYSQL mysql DATABASE-NAME
zpty -r MYSQL
```

and execute it, nothing is printed.

If I remove the -b in the shellscript

```
Reading table information for completion of table and column names
You can turn off this feature to get a quicker startup with -A

Welcome to the MariaDB monitor.  Commands end with ; or \g.
Your MySQL connection id is 449
Serv
```

is printed. Then the script freezes.

In general I notice some very incoherent behaviour. Is this a bug? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `mysql` is scriptable. You shouldn't need to use things like `expect`/`zpty`. In any case with `-b` (non-blocking), the `zpty -r` will return nothing unless you give mysql some time to write something beforehand. Which explains your behaviour.

Comment: Not if I want to do `BEGIN; STUFF;` transactions and ask the user whether he wants to commit or rollback, as far as I know. This is one of the usecases I am preparing this for

Comment: OK. I see your point. Then you'd need to wait for the mysql prompts (see the `zpty -r` variant with a PATTERN or read the output line-by-line). You'd probably be better off using `expect` or similar that can do more out of the box. At which point you may want to consider using a programming language with a proper mysql API instead.

Comment: See also the `--pager` command in `mysql` which you might be able to use to interact with `mysql` via a named pipe. (`--pager='cat > some-fifo'`, send commands via a pipe to `mysql` and read the results via `some-fifo`)